# CoffeeScript compiler API

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I am working in CoffeeScript (writing a Cakefile). I would like to compile some other CoffeeScript files, à la

```
coffee -o lib -c src
```

I could launch the above command in a child process, but this approach has cross-platform issues and makes error handling difficult. I'd much rather use an API.

I'd be happy to use the exact functions from [command.coffee](http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/command.html), but I can't work out how.

Addendum: I see [`require('coffee-script').compile`](http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/coffee-script.html), which compiles a string to another string. That would still leave me to do the grunt work of looping over files and subfolders and writing the output.

Comment: If you too would find a richer API useful, comment on the feature request on Github https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/2386

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The API you're looking for is in [coffee-script.coffee](http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/coffee-script.html). It exports a [`compile`](http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/coffee-script.html#section-6) function that does what it says on the tin.

To use command.coffee's [`run`](http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/command.html#section-7) function directly you'd have to first overwrite [`process.argv`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.1/api/process.html#process.argv) with the options you would have passed on the command line.

Comment: Thanks I tried over-writing `process.argv` but I failed to pull it off. Do you have an example?

Comment: This works for me: `command = require 'coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command`, `process.argv.push '-o', 'lib', '-c', 'src'`, `command.run()`.

Comment: Another observation `run` appears to return before it's finished

Comment: @MattHickford Yes it's asynchronous as can be expected in a Node.js package. The source is straightforward—ultimately all compile options call [`compileScript`](http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/command.html#section-9), and there you can see that it emits "success" and "failure" events. These events pass a `task` object and on `success` that object has an `output` property.

Comment: Can I give `run` a callback ?

Comment: No, but you can [add an event listener](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.7/api/events.html) e.g. `CoffeeScript.on( "success", function( task ) { ... } );`, which is just as good.

Answer (score 7):

Just use node's `fs` API + `coffeescript.compile`:

```
fs = require 'fs'
coffee = require 'coffee-script'

fs.readFile 'source.coffee', 'utf8', (err, data) ->
    compiled = coffee.compile data
    fs.writeFile 'source.js', compiled, (err) ->
        console.log "Done."
```

Also take a look at coffeescript's own Cakefile (uses child processes): https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/blob/master/Cakefile

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jordan and Linus I wrote:

```
 command = require('iced-coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command')
 process.argv[2..]=['-o','lib','-c','src']
 command.run()
```

Outstanding issues: the `run` function returns early and there isn't a callback to report error :\